# How to share with the android studio messenger SDK

Tags: android, sdk, messenger

I tried to share with [the android studio messenger SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android?sdk=maven), but i really don't understand how it works.

I have my messenger app id, and set up in my manifest, installed the SDK with maven.

I added my button with "messenger_button_send_blue_round.xml".

I have my code come from the tutorial with:

```
ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
    ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(contentUri, "image/jpeg")
        .setMetaData("{ \"image\" : \"trees\" }")
        .build();

if (mPicking) {
    MessengerUtils.finishShareToMessenger(this, shareToMessengerParams);
} else {  
    MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(
        this,
        REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER,
        shareToMessengerParams);
}
```

I now have 2 question:

1) REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER is always red, i have to change it to "1".

2) How to link the button click to this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code is use to share on messenger (working great in prod so far):

```
public void shareOnMessenger (SbElem sbElem) {
    // COPY TEMP FILE FROM LOCAL APP TO PUBLIC FOLDER
    final String newPath = getNewPathFromSbElem(sbElem);
    final File newFile = new File(newPath);
    final Uri newUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), newFile);
    // HAD TO SET IT TO 1, CAN'T FIND THE PUBLIC NAME ??
    final Integer SHARE_TO_MESSENGER_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    String mimeType = "audio/*";
    ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams = ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(newUri, mimeType).build();
    MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(this, SHARE_TO_MESSENGER_REQUEST_CODE, shareToMessengerParams);
}
```

Comment: Please add a better description to what are you doing in this code. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)